# jenkins custom page or plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

need for advice.

I would like to create a page with an upload form on jenkins, and then use an API (with the content filled in the form and send it to an API).

Is there an existing solution or is it some kind of custome thing ?

If it's a custom solution, how do I go about it ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to put your custom HTML under $JENKINS_HOME/userContent. The only caveat there is that end users need to be authenticated to Jenkins in order to access the content.

[User Content](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/User+Content)

Comment: Tjx for the answer! The API will generated file in response, with only HTML, that would be ok ? user will able to get the file ?

Comment: Presumably the API would respond with HTML, not with a file that is stored at the OS level. As long as the user is able to view the form that you've stored under userContent, they would also be able to process the response.